# Mariadb Randomly Shuts Down

Tags: docker, mariadb, podman

I have maraidb installed (docker.io/library/mariadb:10.7.8) in a Podman container and around every 24 hours or so it randomly shuts down. The thing is it does not crash according to the log but shuts down gracefully but I have no idea what is triggering it to such down. The only applications I have connected to it are Bookstack and Vikunja and none of those have root or shutdown privileges. It is not a crontab because the time it shuts down is never exactly the same. Could I get some help here please? Below are the logs.

*

```
2023-03-22 23:32:09 0 [Note] mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2023-03-22 23:32:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2023-03-22 23:32:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-03-22 23:32:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2023-03-22 23:32:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 230322 23:32:09
2023-03-22 23:32:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2023-03-22 23:32:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 13032624; transaction id 10401
2023-03-22 23:32:09 0 [Note] mariadbd: Shutdown complete
```

- 

Comment: It's a shutdown request from outside of mariadb - it could be anything in your environment. I don't know that there is much someone without access to your environment can do.

Comment: So I figured out what is was. It has something to do with running podman in rootless mode. When I run it as root it is fine, so the issue definitely seems to be podman. Thanks anyway.